# SQL: SUMming certain items in a column and subtracting it from another figure in that column

Tags: sql, database, variables, plsql, sum

Sorry about the title. It might be a bit confusing! The sample table I'm working with is given below:

```
     ID         Quantity         Type
 -----------------------------------------------
     1             14             PO
     1              2             PO  
     1              4             MH  
     1              3             MH
     1              2             MH
     2             16             PO
     2             12             MH
     2              9             MH
```

Here's what I want to do. I want to sum all quantities of ID = 1 and Type = PO (14 + 2) as SUM_IN. I then want to sum all quantities of ID = 1 and Type = MH (4 + 3 + 2) as SUM_OUT. Once I have this done I want to compare the two and return values only where SUM_OUT > SUM_IN. So for ID = 1 would not be returned where as ID = 2 would, because (12 + 9)  > 16.

Is there a way to do this in SQL or will I need to use PL/SQL and variables for the task. I have very little experience in PL/SQL, but logically it seems that variables would be the easiest way to solve the problem. I know that select statements can be stored in variables but I'm not sure how to. Here are my two SQL selects anyway

```
  SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM_IN
  FROM TRANSLOG
  WHERE TYPE IN ('PO')
  AND ID = '1'

  SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM_OUT
  FROM TRANSLOG
  WHERE TYPE IN ('MH')
  AND ID = '1'
```

So if I could set both these to variables, the task shouldn't be too difficult, right???

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tagged you question with `plsql` tag I assume that the RDBMS you are goint to execute query against is Oracle. If so, then here is another approach(using [DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions049.htm#i1017437) function
) to get the result set you want.

```
select *
  from (select id
             , sum(Quantity*decode(tp, 'PO', 1, 0)) as sum_in
             , sum(Quantity*decode(tp, 'MH', 1, 0)) as sum_out
         from t1
        group by id
        order by id  )
 where sum_out > sum_in
```

Result:

```
ID    SUM_IN    SUM_OUT
-----------------------
 2     16        21
```

If you want to display the rest of the columns along with `sum_in`, `sum_out` the following query might be in handy:

```
select id
     , quantity
     , Tp
     , sum_in
     , sum_out
  from (select id
             , quantity
             , tp
             , sum(Quantity*decode(tp, 'PO', 1, 0)) over(partition by id) as sum_in
             , sum(Quantity*decode(tp, 'MH', 1, 0)) over(partition by id) as sum_out
         from t1
       )
 where sum_out > sum_in
```

Result:

```
Id    Quantity    Tp    Sum_In    Sum_Out 
---------------------------------------------
2      16         PO     16        21 
2      12         MH     16        21 
2      9          MH     16        21
```

Comment: Will this code only work on 2 id's? There are 100's of different IDs in my table, so it needs to iterate through each ID. I probably should have specified this. Thanks for your help Nicholas!

Comment: It will work for every possible ID you have. `With` statement just represents sample data - data you've provided in your question. Hence you see only ID = 2. With different data you will get different result. Try query(s) on your real data.

Answer (score 2):

```
select ID, 
    sum ( Quantity * case Type when 'po' then 1 else 0 end ) as SUM_IN,
    sum ( Quantity * case Type when 'mh' then 1 else 0 end ) as SUM_OUT
from translog
group by ID
having sum ( Quantity * case Type when 'po' then 1 else -1 end ) < 0
```

Comment: Thats great mate, but where is it doing the comparison of whether SUM_OUT > SUM_IN ? Thanks

Comment: @user1619264 In the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.SUM_OUT > a.SUM_IN then b.SUM_OUT else '' END as SUM_OUT,
       CASE WHEN b.SUM_OUT > a.SUM_IN then a.SUM_IN else '' END as SUM_IN
FROM

(SELECT ID,SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM_IN
FROM TRANSLOG
WHERE TYPE IN ('PO')
AND ID = '1'
GROUP BY ID,Type
) a

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT ID,SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM_OUT
FROM TRANSLOG
WHERE TYPE IN ('MH')
AND ID = '1'
GROUP BY ID,Type
) b

ON a.ID=b.ID
```

Comment: Should the "AND ID = '1'" come before the group by clause?

Comment: No problem. Its also saying that its expecting a FROM statement after line 8. Is the a'AS' causing this?

Comment: I am really sorry,In hurry I did not check the answer properly.I was missing from key word.Check the updated answer

Comment: Haha. No problem at all. Really appreciate the help!! :)

Comment: For some reason its still expecting the FROM clause! I'm sure its something silly on my end. Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: there also seems to be a problem with the "" in line 1 and two. It gives me an illegal zero-length identifier error. I tried adding blank space this didn't work. I'm sorry for all the questions and problems. I'm kind of new to all this!!

Comment: OK. that gave me an error saying that it expected an NUMBER but it got a char. So i changed the '' to a 0 and the code ran. But it did not return any data?

Comment: Ohh my query is for sql server