# SUM field not summing

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, plsql

Similar to my last question. Heres my code:

```
  SELECT TR.ITEMNO,
      SUM ( TR.TRANS_QUAN * CASE TR.TRANS_TYPE WHEN 'PO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS SUM_IN,
      SUM ( TR.TRANS_QUAN * CASE TR.TRANS_TYPE WHEN 'MH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS SUM_OUT
  FROM IQMS.TRANSLOG TR
  WHERE TR.ITEMNO = '200672'
  GROUP BY TR.ITEMNO
  HAVING SUM ( TR.TRANS_QUAN * CASE TR.TRANS_TYPE WHEN 'PO' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END ) < 0
  ORDER BY TR.ITEMNO
```

The code is running fine but it is not summing anything for SUM_OUT. I know for a fact however that there are numbers there to be summed. Is there something obvious that I am missing? Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: take a look at my answer in your previous question. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617153/sql-summing-certain-items-in-a-column-and-subtracting-it-from-another-figure-in/12618508#12618508)

Comment: Hard to find any "mistake" without seeing some sample data. Can you please provide a subset of your data that allows for reproducing the case?

Comment: ... Besides, please explain the idea behind your `HAVING` clause

Comment: Are `PO` and `MH` the only possible values for `TRANS_TYPE`, or are there other values in the table?

Comment: Nicholas has solved the problem!! thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Try...

```
SUM (TR.TRANS_QUAN * CASE TR.TRANS_TYPE WHEN 'PO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
OVER(PARTITION BY TR.ITEMNO)  AS SUM_IN,

SUM ( TR.TRANS_QUAN * CASE TR.TRANS_TYPE WHEN 'MH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
OVER(PARTITION BY TR.ITEMNO)  AS SUM_OUT,
```